# Is taking a screenshot of my VPN settings safe?

Tags: vpn

I had a problem with my VPN Service, and I asked a guy in a forum for help, and he told me to screenshot all of my settings in my VPN application. Is this safe, if not, what setting should I redact?

Is there something I need to hide from others, and is it safe to say what VPN service I use ?

Comment: What data is on this screenshot?

Comment: @nakE: "It's related to VPN."* - sure, lots of things are related to VPN. That does not mean that everything should be put into the same question. *"Everything about the VPN."* - so the username and password are included too?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Have you seen your password in any app settings ?

Comment: @nakE please be more specific in your question and list all your data you would like to publish. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: @CDRohling VPN Version, VPN type (RAV, STSIV, etc..), VPN company (NordVPN, etc..), IP....

Comment: @nakE: The information listed so far are not a problem too share. As for the unknown *"IP...."* nothing can be said since it is unknown what *"...."* is. In general: consider that it is you who want help so you should make it easy for others to help you and provide the necessary information. The quality of the question usually effects the quality of the help you get.

Answer (score -2):

Its not a good security practice to share your personal stuff online.

There is no problem in sharing screenshot unless you are sharing your vpn's configuration file.

Comment: The OP has not stated what is in the screenshot. It sounds like the data being shared is configuration data. And not all VPN software has a *configuration file*.